# Браузер перекрывает стили,что делать?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Браузер перекрывает стили. Я начинаю прописывать одно,второе.... и реагирует при обновлении не на всё.
Я чистила !полностью!, всю историю. Я удаляла и по новой устанавливала браузер. Если в html прописать стили,всё видит. В css,нет. Что делать?...(невозможно работать.)

Comment: Правильно ли подключен файл css?

Comment: может вы какие-то не такие стили пишете?

Comment: Была такая история с Opera. Пункты dropdownlist'а не окрашивались в цвета. Перенёс на другой хостинг и всё починилось. Попробуйте установить новый браузер (который ещё не использовали) и потестите на нём. Сразу узнаете, ваша ли это ошибка или дело в другом

Comment: Попробуйте в консоли разработчика вкладка 'Network' поставить галочку возле 'Disable cache' и перезагрузить страницу с открытой консолью.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не обновляете версию css-файла при выгрузке изменений. Браузер Chrome и некоторые другие браузеры на движке Web Kit сейчас не обновляют без аппаратной перезагрузки и чистки кэша ранее загруженные и закэшированные файлы (в т.ч. файлы стилей).

Чтобы изменения всегда отображались добавляйте к вашему файлу номер версии. Например, так это делается на StackOverflow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/all.css?v=2f74b6273bbf">
```

Как видите, после файла идет параметр `v=2f74b6273bbf`, который принудительно сбрасывает кэш и загружает файл с сервера. Вы можете при каждых новых изменениях своего файла делать такой же параметр или увеличивать число на единицу (например, `all.css?11`). Главное, для каждой новой версии должно быть уникальное значение.

В качестве разового решения поможет аппаратная перезагрузка (это не F5 или CTRL+R). Открываете в Chrome инструменты разработчика, потом кликаете на иконке перезагрузки (которая слева перед адресной строкой) и выбираете "Очистка кэша и аппаратная перезагрузка".

Comment: Или можно использовать режим инкогнито :) Или сафари с отключенными кэшами.